# ReplyingKafkaTemplate with KafkaTransactionManager raise Exception

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I am developing a microservice that needs to make use of synchronous call under transaction with Spring Boot and Kafka.To do this, I use ReplyKafkaTemplate with KafkaTransactionManager. However ReplyKafkaTemplate apparently doesn't work with transactions! The Kafka message needs to be processed transactionally, so it won't be lost in case of failure. However when I add KafkaTransactionManager settings an exception is thrown.

**Requirements:**

Spring Boot: 2.3.1

Kafka: 2.5.0

Spring Kafka: 2.5.2

**Scenario 1:** 
When adding bean KafkaTransactionManager, the error is thrown during application startup: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaTransactionManager' defined in class path resource.

Configuration:
application.yml

```
kafka:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  topic:
    request-topic: request-topic
    request-reply-topic: request-reply-topic
    consumer-group: request-reply-group
  producer:
    transactionIdPrefix: "kafka-tx-"
```

---

KafkaSettings.java

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaSettings {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.request-reply-topic}")
    private String requestReplyTopic;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.consumer-group}")
    private String consumerGroup;

    @Bean
    public KafkaTransactionManager kafkaTransactionManager() {
        KafkaTransactionManager ktm = new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory());
        ktm.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
        return ktm;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "coffeeshop-consumer-group-id");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Object> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        return pf;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
        final JsonDeserializer<Object> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
        jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), jsonDeserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<?, ?, ?> replyingKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> pf, KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> container){
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate(pf, container);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, Object> cf) {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(requestReplyTopic);
        return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

---

CoffeeController.java

```
@RequestMapping
@RestController
public class CoffeeController {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Coffee, Coffee> replyingKafkaTemplate;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.request-topic}")
    String requestTopic;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.request-reply-topic}")
    String requestReplyTopic;

    private RequestReplyFuture<String, Coffee, Coffee> requestReplyFuture;

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(value=“/coffee/create",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Coffee create (@RequestBody Coffee coffee) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ProducerRecord<String, Coffee> record = new ProducerRecord<String, Coffee>(requestTopic, coffee);
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, requestReplyTopic.getBytes()));

        requestReplyFuture = replyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);

        ConsumerRecord<String, Coffee> consumerRecord = requestReplyFuture.get();
        return consumerRecord.value();
    }
}
```

---

CreateCoffee.java

```
@Component
public class CreateCoffee {
     @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.request-topic}")
     @SendTo
      public Coffee listen(Coffee coffee) {
            coffee.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        return coffee;
      }
}
```

---

Coffee.java

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Coffee {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private UUID id;

    @JsonProperty("price")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @JsonProperty("varietal")
    private String varietal;

    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    private Integer quantity;

    @JsonProperty("amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;


    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getVarietal() {
        return varietal;
    }

    public void setVarietal(String varietal) {
        this.varietal = varietal;
    }

    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return price.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(quantity));
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [coffeeshop/kafka/KafkaSettings.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager]: Factory method 'kafkaTransactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'ProducerFactory' must support transactions
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at coffeeshop.CoffeeShopApplication.main(CoffeeShopApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager]: Factory method 'kafkaTransactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'ProducerFactory' must support transactions
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'ProducerFactory' must support transactions
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager.<init>(KafkaTransactionManager.java:88) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at coffeeshop.kafka.KafkaSettings.kafkaTransactionManager(KafkaSettings.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at coffeeshop.kafka.KafkaSettings$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa27e75a.CGLIB$kafkaTransactionManager$2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at coffeeshop.kafka.KafkaSettings$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa27e75a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$498ae027.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at coffeeshop.kafka.KafkaSettings$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa27e75a.kafkaTransactionManager(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

**Scenario 2:**
Manually configuring ProducerFactory by invoking **transactionCapable()** and adding **setTransactionIdPrefix ("coffee-prefix")** the following error is thrown:

No transaction is in process; possible solutions: run the template operation within the scope of a template.executeInTransaction()

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Object> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    pf.transactionCapable();
    pf.setTransactionIdPrefix("coffee-prefix");
    return pf;
}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction is in process; possible solutions: run the template operation within the scope of a template.executeInTransaction() operation, start a transaction with @Transactional before invoking the template method, run in a transaction started by a listener container when consuming a record
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.getTheProducer(KafkaTemplate.java:636) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:548) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:385) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(ReplyingKafkaTemplate.java:323) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(ReplyingKafkaTemplate.java:302) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at coffeeshop.web.controllers.CoffeeController.create(CoffeeController.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

**Expected results:**

Request:

```
curl -X POST  http://localhost:8080/coffee/create -d '{"varietal": "Yellow Bourbon","quantity": 3, "price": 30.00}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" | python -m json.tool
```

Response:

```
{
   "id": "26eca82d-8bd0-4fd4-a743-5de52f9b6d4f",
   "price": 30.0,
   "varietal": "Yellow Bourbon",
   "quantity": 3,
   "amount": 90.0
}
```

Comment: I've got the same error described in the scenario 1 and found that the `    transactionIdPrefix: "kafka-tx-"` configuration in my `applicatoin.yaml` was the cause. I only managed to fix it by configuring the prefix in the code rather than in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you need a `spring` prefix:

```
  spring:
    kafka:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      topic:
        request-topic: request-topic
        request-reply-topic: request-reply-topic
        consumer-group: request-reply-group
      producer:
        transactionIdPrefix: "kafka-tx-"
```

In either case, you need to add `@Transactional` to the `create` method so that the transaction manager will start a transaction.

Or, you can use

```java
    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(value=“/coffee/create",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Coffee create (@RequestBody Coffee coffee) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ProducerRecord<String, Coffee> record = new ProducerRecord<String, Coffee>(requestTopic, coffee);
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, requestReplyTopic.getBytes()));

        return replyingKafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(template -> {
            requestReplyFuture = replyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);

            ConsumerRecord<String, Coffee> consumerRecord = requestReplyFuture.get();
            return consumerRecord.value();
        });
    }
```

The error seems quite clear:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction is in process; possible solutions: run the template operation within the scope of a template.executeInTransaction() operation, start a transaction with @Transactional before invoking the template method, run in a transaction started by a listener container when consuming a record

By the way; it's best to use `get(timeout, TimeUnit...)` on the future, to avoid hanging indefinitely when no reply is returned for some reason.

**EDIT**

However, this will never work with a consumer with `isolation.level=read_committed` because the consumer won't see the request until it is committed and we won't commit until the reply is received, which will never happen, so we'll time out and abort the transaction.

`sendAndReceive()` can simply not be used in a transaction.

The only solution is to do a send and add your own listener to get the reply (and correlate it to a request).

Comment: Gary, after changing the files, a new exception was thrown `org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException` and `ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed `, resulting in a ReplyTimeout. 
Both `@Transaction` and `replyKafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction()` were tested, but the results were the same.

Comment: Yeah - we have a catch-22 here; we can't run `sendAndReceive()` in a transaction because the transaction won't be committed until the reply is received, which means that a consumer (with `isolation.level=read_committed`) will never see the request. We simply can't support `sendAndReceive` in a transaction - you will have to use send together with a listener container and do your own correlation.

Comment: @GaryRussell I get the very same exception **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'ProducerFactory' must support transactions** when the app starts just by adding `transaction-id-prefix` property to *application.yaml*. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should ask a new question showing your code, configuration and stacktrace. Include version information too.