Spring Boot Kafka Issue With Transactionality When Using ReplyingKafkaTemplate
I want to use ReplyingKafkaTemplate in order to implement Request-Reply messaging pattern with Kafka having end-to-end transactionality. I have tried many solutions and I concluded to the following code having these two awkward issues without finding working solution:

When I use read_commited isolation level in consumer (uncomment code line in the below configuration code: consumerFactoryConfigProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");) I get "Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.KafkaReplyTimeoutException: Reply timed out".

When I don't use read_commited isolation level in consumer (comment code line in the below configuration code: consumerFactoryConfigProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");) I get "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction is in process; possible solutions: run the template operation within the scope of a template.executeInTransaction() operation, start a transaction with @Transactional before invoking the template method, run in a transaction started by a listener container when consuming a record".


With using KafkaTemplate I am able to send event to the target topic and many others with transactionality. The issues arise with ReplyingKafkaTemplate, I cannot figure out how to properly implement it.
Do you have any ideas how to overcome these to issues and have a working solution?
Configuration
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Event> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, acks);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, transactionId);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, bufferMemory);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, maxRequestSize);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retries);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, batchSize);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, lingerMs);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, compressionType);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, requestTimeoutMs);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, deliveryTimeoutMs);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Event> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Event> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Event, Event> replyingKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Event> producerFactory,
                                                                             ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Event> repliesContainer) {
        ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Event, Event> replyingKafkaTemplate = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory, repliesContainer);
        replyingKafkaTemplate.setSharedReplyTopic(true);

        return replyingKafkaTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            KafkaTemplate<String, Event> kafkaTemplate) {
        Map<String, Object> consumerFactoryConfigProps = new HashMap<>();
        consumerFactoryConfigProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        consumerFactoryConfigProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        consumerFactoryConfigProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");

        ConsumerFactory<String, Event> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                consumerFactoryConfigProps, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Event.class));

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event> kafkaListenerContainerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate);

        return kafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Event> repliesContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event> kafkaListenerContainerFactory) {
        Properties repliesContainerConfigProps = new Properties();
        repliesContainerConfigProps.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest"); // so the new group doesn't get old replies

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Event> repliesContainer =
                kafkaListenerContainerFactory.createContainer("reply_topic");
        repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()); // unique
        repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setKafkaConsumerProperties(repliesContainerConfigProps);

        return repliesContainer;
    }

Producer
    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    public void sendSaveFileEvent(SubmissionDto submissionDto) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        SaveFileEvent outgoingSaveFileEvent = saveFileEventFactory
                .createEvent(submissionDto.getIncomingFileDto(), false, null);

        ProducerRecord<String, Event> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, outgoingSaveFileEvent.key(), outgoingSaveFileEvent);
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, "reply_topic".getBytes()));
        RequestReplyFuture<String, Event, Event> replyFuture = replyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
        SendResult<String, Event> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get();

        log.debug("Reply Future Record Metadata: {} ", sendResult.getRecordMetadata());

        ConsumerRecord<String, Event> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get();

        log.debug("incomingSaveFileEvent: {}", consumerRecord.value());
    }

Consumer
    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    @KafkaListener(id = "server",
            topics = "${application.kafka.saveFile.topicName}")
    @SendTo
    public Event handleSaveFileEvent(SaveFileEvent incomingSaveFileEvent) {
        try {
            log.debug("Received message: {}", incomingSaveFileEvent);

            SaveFileEvent outgoingSaveFileEvent = saveFileEventFactory
                    .createEvent(incomingSaveFileEvent.getIncomingFileDto(), true, "Success");

            return outgoingSaveFileEvent;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error", ex);

            return incomingSaveFileEvent;
        }
    }

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks a lot for your time.
I tried many proposed solutions from stackoverflow and I didn't manage to find a working solution. I want to propely configure ReplyingKafkaTemplate to work with transactionality.

Deep dividing in bibliography and making some more test I concluded to: 1. Isolation level read_commited in consumer will not work and the behaviour is correct. As it is mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450018/replyingkafkatemplate-with-kafkatransactionmanager-raise-exception the transaction won't be committed until the reply is received, which means that a consumer will never see the request. 2. On the other hand, with the absense of Isolation level read_commited and the usage of @Transactional the above code should work.
If you have any ideas or solutions please advise.
